# How to mimic iPod time remaining and time played scrubbing labels

Tags: ios4, ipod, uislider

I have an audio scrubber consisting of a `UISlider` and two `UILabel`s on each side to mimic the iPod's time played and time remaining labels.  I can update the labels with the slider's position, but the labels only jump to each new seek time.

How can I make the labels increment by seconds--so the labels go through every second and minute quickly between the old time and the new seek time as you slide the slider?  My slider is currently set to [0.0, 1.0] and it is continuous.

Is there a way to override touchesMoved: for the slider maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  The issue wasn't my code being incorrect.  It was I was pulling the `currentPlaybackTime` value from a `MPMoviePlayerController`, and that was lagging the labels.  I removed that and used the new slider value and it worked great.